# Facebook Javascript SDK Login not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer

I have the following code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head>
    <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
        function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            alert('statusChangeCallback');
            // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
            // app know the current login status of the person.
            // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
            // for FB.getLoginStatus().
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                alert('1');
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                testAPI();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                alert('2');
                // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                  'into this app.';
            } else {
                alert('3');
                // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
                // they are logged into this app or not.
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                  'into Facebook.';
            }
        }

        // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
        // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
        // code below.
        function checkLoginState() {
            alert('checkLoginState');
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                alert('getLoginStatus 2');
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            alert('init');
            FB.init({
                appId: 'xxx[correct appid given],
                cookie: true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                // the session
                xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version: 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
            });

            // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
            // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
            // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
            // the callback you provide.  They can be:
            //
            // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
            // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
            // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
            //    your app or not.
            //
            // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                alert('getLoginStatus 1');
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });

        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
        // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
        function testAPI() {
            alert('testAPI');
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                alert('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                  'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
            });
        }
    </script>
    <!--
      Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
      the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
      the FB.login() function when clicked.
    -->

    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
    </fb:login-button>

    <div id="status">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The following is the sequence of alerts I get when I try this:

1. "init"
2. "getLoginStatus 1"
3. "statusChangeCallback"
4. "3"
5. Click on Login button and log on to Facebook.
6. Window closes. No more alerts displayed. The status text doesn't change.

Why doesn't the above code work in IE? It doesn't even get to "getLoginStatus2" or call statusChangeCallback again after step 5.

Comment: I don't think it even gets to onlogin="checkLoginState();" in the fb element.

Comment: Actually the flow of control is not working properly you are not able to login in the first time and it is not able to call  the testapi(),please check if you have given permission in the fb app please try it with other browsers[it may not solve it but just try].

Comment: It works in other browsers. I tried it in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: This issue is a common occurring one, just do a google search and you will find that IE is not compatible, https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LENP_enIN564IN564&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=facebook+and+internet+explorer+compatibility+issue

Comment: I am experiencing something similar in a react application. The facebook dialog loads, l login to facebook successfully, but the dialog never closes off or notifies my app so my app can't login.

Comment: any solutions guys :D